# Bypass SSO siteminder for a page inside a website

Tags: single-sign-on, siteminder

I have a Siteminder SSO enabled website. Here i need to access a page inside website without sso auth. But now it redirects to login page automaticaly. Please help.

Comment: Hi Renu, This seems old but I am facing same issue, When I am trying to send a request to the page using HTTPWEBREQUEST it keeps redirecting to login page. I am using C# for my application. Did you find a solution to this problem. If so could  you please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the configuration of your Siteminder policy server to specify that the url of the page you want to access is not protected.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new unprotected realm for the page you want unprotected